# Migrating custom CMS website to Wordpress - how to add links correctly?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm migrating a website that has a custom CMS to Wordpress. We're talking about a giant site with thousands of posts.

At the moment I'm at the stage where I extract the content in JSON files by category and then insert them to the Wordpress DB via MySQL. I've even moved all the images and adjusted the URL using the PHP script.

However, my problem is with links inside the content. Some link to external sites (not a problem), while others link to other posts in the old site. How can I take those links and link to the correct, new Wordpress URL?

My link structure ideally would be /category/post/ in Wordpress. The old structure is similar, except the post URL is sometimes different by a few characters to the one coming out of Wordpress. It's not necessarily "post-title-is-the-url", sometimes it has a suffix like "_2". How do I go around the problem with the suffixes?

Comment: Maybe one htaccess rule per suffix in htaccess file?

Comment: Yeah but it's impossible for me to know what each suffix is and how many different ones I have when there are thousands of posts.